# Drupal 7 + Apache Solr Search + Solr 5.5.x

Tags: search, drupal, solr, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have set up a Drupal 7 with Apache Solr Search module installed, and also have set up a solr server which can be reached by the Apache Solr Search module.

However, the indexing can't be done and sol keeps showing the following error

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=jbsxar/node/111]
>   Error adding field 'label'='NAMM Show Artists Announced' msg=For input
>   string: "NAMM Show Artists Announced"     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getLuceneDocument(AddUpdateCommand.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:280)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:214)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:335)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:934)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1089)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:712)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:250)
>     at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:155)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2102)    at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:654)
>     at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:460)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:257)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:208)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NAMM Show Artists
>   Announced"    at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)  at
>   java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)   at
>   org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.createField(TrieField.java:755)  at
>   org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.createFields(TrieField.java:806)     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addField(DocumentBuilder.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:122)
>     ... 56 more

I have copied all the solr-conf file from the Apache Solr Module to the solr core conf directory. And now I totally have no idea why the indexing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should install an explicit schema for Solr instead of relying on the schemaless mode. Solr is trying to parse your label as a number, since that's probably what the first document you submitted had for that field:

> Caused by: **java.lang.NumberFormatException**: For input string: "NAMM Show Artists Announced" at

You can either edit `schema.xml` by hand, or if you're using the managed schema, use the Admin UI to add the fields and associated types yourself.